# Problemas com o Charts Laravel, sempre erro de classe não encontrada!

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Senhores, estou usando o *Laravel 5.7* e com o seguinte problema

```
Class 'ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts' not found
```

Fiz a instalação dele corretamente:

```
composer require consoletvs/charts
```

adicionei no `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    ....
    ....
    ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    ....
    ....
    'Charts' => ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
],
```

Criei o model e `Controller` necessários

```
$products = Product::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))->get();
    $chart = Charts::database($products, 'bar', 'highcharts')
              ->title("Product Details")
              ->elementLabel("Total Products")
              ->dimensions(1000, 500)
              ->responsive(true)
              ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);


    $pie_chart = Charts::create('pie', 'highcharts')
            ->title('Pie Chart Demo')
            ->labels(['Product 1', 'Product 2', 'Product 3'])
            ->values([15,25,50])
            ->dimensions(1000,500)
            ->responsive(true);
```

e na minha `View`

```
{!! $chart->render() !!}
```

Onde posso estar errando?

Comment: Você rodou o comando `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=charts_config`?

Comment: Sim rodei sim @sant0will

Answer (score 0):

Como você está colocando o caminho para a classe completo, adicione `\` no início.

Mais informações aqui:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.qualified

Se você não colocar a barra no ínicio, ele vai pegar o namespace atual e tentar encontrar (ex.: Se estiver em "App", vai virar: "\App\Console...").

```
<?php
//....
'providers' => [
    ....
    ....
    \ConsoleTVs\Charts\ChartsServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    ....
    ....
    'Charts' => \ConsoleTVs\Charts\Facades\Charts::class,
],
```